# Show that $\pm 1$ are the only eigenvalues of the linear operator $f$ as the transpose of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over $K$ under addition and let the linear operator $f$ be given by $f(A)=A^{T}$, where $A^T$ denotes the transpose of matrix $A$.
>
> 1. Show that $\pm 1$ are the only eigenvalues of $f$.
> 2. Suppose the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$. What are the dimensions of the eigenspaces $E(1)$ and $E(-1)$?

Eigenvalues are found from equation: $f(v)=\lambda v$, therefore we have $v^T=\lambda v$, I don't understand how this shows $\lambda =\pm 1$.

I know that $\dim E(1)+\dim E(2)=n$ would this suffice for the second part?

Comment: Very good explanation, although reading the post I raised the question of what is the Characteristic Polynomial of $f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then $f(A) = \lambda A$ for some $A \ne 0$. Then $A = (A^T)^T = f(f(A)) = f(\lambda A) = \lambda^2 A$, so $\lambda^2 = 1$ (since $A \ne 0$), hence $\lambda = \pm 1$.

Eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues always intersect trivially, so $E(1) \cap E(-1) = 0$. On the other hand, $E(1)$ consists of symmetric matrices ($A^T = A$), and $E(-1)$ consists of skew-symmetric matrices ($A^T = -A$), and in characteristic $\ne 2$, every square matrix $A$ is a sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrix - explicitly $A = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) + \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$. Thus $\text{Mat}_{n \times n} = E(1) \oplus E(-1)$. Now $E(1)$ has dimension $n+1 \choose 2$ (as entries in the upper triangular block can be chosen arbitrarily), so $E(-1)$ has dimension $n^2 - {n+1 \choose 2} = {n-1 \choose 2}$.

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks.

Comment: @Dansmith: You're quite welcome

Answer (score 1):

$f(A)=\lambda A$, hence $f(f(A))=\lambda f(A)=\lambda^2 A$, but $f(f(A))=A$, then 
$A=\lambda^2 A$, so $\lambda^2=1$.

Comment: Literally just realized it and was typing in that answer, but thanks for the quick response, do you know the part about the dimensions of the eigenspaces? Thanks.